# How can I make my PC always take the first local IP from the WiFi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I share multiple devices on a single WiFi router. They all are assigned local IP addresses (192.168.x.x) depending on a first-connect, first-assigned basis I think.

Is there a way to make one device (my PC) always take a predefined local IP address (192.168.1.2) regardless of whether it was connected before or after other devices?

[image: scr]

**EDIT:** In addition to the answer, I've found an easier workaround that works for me: Assign IP address `192.168.1.`**`100`**  to my PC. Obviously because I'll never connect upto 100 devices.

Comment: The router usually has an option to set the IP by MAC address or host name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When using DHCP, the (Wi-Fi) router is the DHCP server, that is, the network host that assigns the IP addresses. The computers do not choose their address from the pool; the router chooses and tells the computer what its address will be.

Therefore, you have two options if you want a computer to always have the same IP address:

## Option 1: IP address reservation

Set up a static IP address reservation in the router, so the router knows to always give your computer the same IP address. How you do this, or whether it is even possible, depends on the type of router you have.

Your screenshot looks like the same [software that Prolink routers use](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/3715/poolsummary.jpg), and if that's true, you'd use one of the "Statically assigned" fields on the "Local Area Network (LAN) Settings" screen.

## Option 2: Static IP address on the computer

Do not use DHCP (on that computer), and set that computer's IP address statically. You will also want to reconfigure the router so it doesn't try to assign that address to anyone else (so that the lowest address it gives out is 192.168.1.3).

If your router does indeed use Prolink software, then you would increase the "Start IP Address" setting to 192.168.1.3, then set your computer's static IP to 192.168.1.2.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer so that people see the difference between quality (yours) and being first to answer (mine).  Well done! +1

Comment: @Everett Thanks for the compliment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Force the IP address.  Assign the IP address to the MAC address of the device in question.

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the IPv4 properties for static models and fill your computer IP address in accordance with the Wi-Fi router's DHCP range.

If you are an administrator on the Wi-Fi router, you can provide a permanent IP address based on mac address computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use mac & ip binding in routers. It will know your device by the mac and keep it ip as reserved. It is a very useful and easy to do thing